# adding a default namespace in xquery

Tags: xquery

I have an xquery file that transforms from a.xml to b.xml. Below is an example of my x-query:

```
<TestMessage>
    <Header>
      <MessageType>
           {for $x in doc("input.xml")//Test/NewHeader return 
        if ($x/MessageType/text() = "FIRST") then "FirstMessageType"
        else "SecondMessageType"
    }   
      </MessageType>
    </Header>
 </TestMessage>
```

This works fine and populates my MessageType properly. But I need to add a namespace as an attribute to the TestMessage element. So, when I do,

```
<TestMessage xmlns="http://www.testsource.com/TestMessage">
    <Header>
      <MessageType>
           {for $x in doc("input.xml")//Test/NewHeader return 
        if ($x/MessageType/text() = "FIRST") then "FirstMessageType"
        else "SecondMessageType"
    }   
      </MessageType>
    </Header>
 </TestMessage>
```

The xquery result has an empty MessageType element. I haven't changed anything except add the namespace in the x-query document. But I don't understand why this gives me a wrong resultant xml.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a default namespace to the `TestMessage` element, that namespace is also applied to the XPath you are executing underneath it: `doc("input.xml")//Test/NewHeader` and `($x/MessageType/text()`.

If that content doesn't have a namespace, then the easiest thing to do would be to declare a namespace prefix in the XML root: `xmlns:test="http://www.testsource.com/TestMessage`, and prefix all of the elements: `<test:TestMessage xmlns:test="http://www.testsource.com/TestMessage>`, `<test:Header>` and so on.

One way to get around this is to execute the no-namespace XQuery code outside of the default-namespaced XML:

```
declare function local:get-message-type()
{
  for $x in doc("input.xml")//Test/NewHeader 
  return 
    if ($x/MessageType/text() = "FIRST") 
    then "FirstMessageType"
    else "SecondMessageType"
};

<TestMessage xmlns="http://www.testsource.com/TestMessage">
    <Header>
      <MessageType>
           { local:get-message-type() }   
      </MessageType>
    </Header>
</TestMessage>
```

Comment: But the root element of my resultant xml should look exactly like this: <TestMessage xmlns="http://www.testsource.com/TestMessage">

Comment: Other than the presentation, there's no difference in the resultant XML using a default namespace or a namespace prefix. Any application will treat them the same. However, see the updated solution for an alternative.

Comment: @wst is correct.  This is called "namespace inheritance" in XQuery.  For more on this, see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/xquery/namespaces#id_49014.

Comment: Wow I was struggling to figure out why I kept getting an empty response from my xpath inside of the xml that had a declared namespace like you do there with xmlns. Using a function outside that namespace to get the info and plug it in thereby inheriting the specified namespace did the trick! I couldn't figure out a cleaner way and I really appreciate this answer!